# Can the column names of an ICompositeUserType be controlled in a FluentNHibernate convention?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I've created an `IUserTypeConvention` convention to use an `ICompositeUserType` implementation on all properties of a matching type:

```
public abstract class CompositeUserTypeConvention<TUserType> 
    : IUserTypeConvention
    where TUserType : ICompositeUserType, new()
{
    public virtual void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        var userType = new TUserType();

        criteria.Expect(x => x.Type == userType.ReturnedClass);
    }

    public virtual void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.CustomType<TUserType>();
    }
}
```

When applying this, FluentNHibernate generates column names for each property of the composite type using a convention of `{memberpropertyname}_{compositepropertyname}`.

In the case of a composite type like `Money` with properties `Amount` and `Currency`, if I were to have a property on my entity called `Price` of type `Money`, the columns expected are called `Price_Currency` and `Price_Amount`.

What I would like is to change this convention to remove the underscore, but I don't know how or if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The `CustomType<T>()` method has an overload which accepts `columnPrefix` as an argument. The default behaviour is to pass the property name + "_" as this value. Specifying the value explicitly gave the desired result:

```
public virtual void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
{
    instance.CustomType<TUserType>(instance.Name);
}
```

Comment: In current versions of FluentNHibernate this overload seems to have been removed. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16935310/684096 for a currently up-to-date answer.